# Unable to run my first program with netbeans and cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, netbeans-8

I am using the Netbeans IDE with Cordova. When i try to run my application it fails and i get the following error.

[image]

Node.js v8.1.3
cordova v7.0.1
Git v2.13.2
os windows

Comment: please include your `package.json` file

Comment: Thanks for participating to StackOverflow. But note that errors need to be provided as **text**, not as **image**. Please edit your question for that.

Comment: Don't post information as image which can be text.

Comment: how add package.json file to project Max